# How do I get a Python program to take in parameters as inputs that come from standard input from the UNIX terminal?

Tags: python

For example - I want to do something like...

```
python DoublePendulum.py INPUT1 INPUT2
```

(where `INPUT1` and `INPUT2` are taken as variable inputs within the DoublePendulum program).

Comment: check out `sys.argv` http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html

Comment: I'm personally a fan of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) as it allows switches/validation/etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

In test.py

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

output

```
Number of arguments: 4 arguments.
Argument List: ['test.py', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
```

Python also provided modules that helps you parse command-line options and arguments.
There are the following modules in the standard library:

- The [getopt](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html) module is similar to GNU getopt.
- The [optparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#module-optparse) module offers object-oriented command line option parsing, optparse was deprecated in version 2.7 of Python [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) is the replacement.

Comment: `optparse` is deprecated as of 2.7. Use `argparse` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$ python test.py one two five something`

inside test.py

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0:1], sys.argv[1:2], sys.argv[2:3], sys.argv[3:4], sys.argv[4:5])
```

**will output as lists:**

> ```
> ['test.py'] ['one'] ['two'] ['five'] ['something']
> ```

```
for my_var in sys.argv:
    print(my_var)
```

**will output: as strings**

> ```
> test.py  
> one  
> two  
> five  
> something
> ```

**I made this function for that returns the parameter you want**

```
def give_me_arg(n):
    num = len(sys.argv)
    if n >= num:
        print("Only enter:>",num,'<-and are this from 0 to ',num-1,':', sys.argv)
        return ''
    else:
        for my_var in sys.argv[n:n+1]:
            return my_var

my_var=give_me_arg(3)
```